# Selenium switch window stop after a specific iteration

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I don't know why I'm getting this error I tried many `exception` to handle my error , but sometimes it goes fluently till a specific page and stops and sometimes it doesn't even starts.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common import exceptions
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

options = Options()

# Create our Players Salaries Dictionary
weekly_wages_players_dataset = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'team', 'weekly wage'])

# We specify our Chrome driver path
path = "C:/Users/Al4D1N/Documents/ChromeDriver_webscraping/chromedriver.exe"
web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)

# Famous Championships
premier_league_url = "https://eurofootballrumours.com/premier-league-players-salaries/"
bundesliga_url = "https://eurofootballrumours.com/bundesliga-players-salaries/"
laliga_url = "https://eurofootballrumours.com/la-liga-players-salaries/"
seriea_url = "https://eurofootballrumours.com/serie-a-players-salaries/"
ligue_fr_url = "https://eurofootballrumours.com/ligue-1-players-salaries/"

championships = [premier_league_url, bundesliga_url, laliga_url, seriea_url, ligue_fr_url]


def players_info(driver, url, weekly_wages_players):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException as e:
        print(e.message)
    sleep(3)
    # Let's get the teams values
    teams = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2")

    for t in teams:
        atags = t.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
        for atag in atags:
            # In each atag, select the href
            href = atag.get_attribute('href')
            print(href)
            # Open a new window
            driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
            driver.get(href)
            sleep(2)
            # We get players infos
            player_team = driver.find_element_by_class_name('wp-caption-text').text

            # We get table content since it has all players name and their weekly wages
            table_id = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "table")
            tbody = table_id.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")
            rows = tbody.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
            for row in rows:
                player_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0].text
                player_week_salary = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1].text
                print(player_name)
                print(player_week_salary)
                # Now we store our result to our dataframe
                weekly_wages_players = weekly_wages_players.append(
                    {'name': player_name, 'team': player_team, 'weekly wage': player_week_salary}, ignore_index=True)

        # Close the tab with URL B
        driver.close()
        # Switch back to the first tab with URL A
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])


# We call our function through all the championships links
for championship in championships:
    players_info(web_driver, championship, weekly_wages_players_dataset)
web_driver.close()

# We store our dataframe in an excel file
weekly_wages_players_dataset.to_excel('Weekly_Players_Wages.xlsx', index=False)
```

And this is the error I get :

> driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id

Comment: You cannot switch after `driver.close()` because that closes the session.

Comment: but it actually just close the new tab opened , if I remove it , it will open infinity of new tabs